# Can't get simple if..elif test to work with testing for a number

Tags: python, if-statement

My assignment is:

> You have been asked to write a program that will give the name of a
>   shape depending on the number of sides. The user can only enter
>   numbers between 3 and 8, if they enter any other number then the
>   program should tell them to enter a number between 3 and 8.

And here's my Python answer:

```
#Sides and shapes
sides = int(input("How many sides on the shape are there? "))
if sides ==3:
    print ("Your shape is the triangle")
if sides ==4:
    print ("Your shape is the square")
if sides ==5:
    print ("Your shape is the pentagon")
if sides ==6:
    print ("Your shape is the hexagon")
if sides ==7:
    print ("Your shape is the heptagon")
if sides ==8:
    print ("Your shape is the octagon")
elif sides != range(3,9):
    print ("You should enter a number between 3 and 8")
```

After the `elif` statement I somehow also need to loop it so that if the person inputs other than 3-8 then it will keep asking for them to enter a number from 3 to 8.

The `elif` statement does not work for some reason and outputs this answer in F5:

```
How many sides on the shape are there? 6
Your shape is the hexagon
You should enter a number between 3 and 8
```

Comment: Why do you think the `elif` should work? Do you know what `range(3, 9)` is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`range()` produces an object of a different type; `integer != range()` is *always* going to be true.

Either test if you integer is outside a range with `<` or `<=` and chaining:

```
elif not (3 <= sides < 9):
    print ("You should enter a number between 3 and 8")
```

or use `not in` to see if the number is outside the range:

```
elif sides not in range(3, 9):
    print ("You should enter a number between 3 and 8")
```

or simply use `elif` on *all* your tests but the first, and `else` for the last branch; it'll picked only if the `if..elif` tests did not match:

```
if sides ==3:
    print ("Your shape is the triangle")
elif sides ==4:
    print ("Your shape is the square")
elif sides ==5:
    print ("Your shape is the pentagon")
elif sides ==6:
    print ("Your shape is the hexagon")
elif sides ==7:
    print ("Your shape is the heptagon")
elif sides ==8:
    print ("Your shape is the octagon")
else:
    print ("You should enter a number between 3 and 8")
```

Note that there is only *one* `if` now; logically, the `elif` and `else` parts belong to that one `if` statement. Any other `if` forms a separate, *new* set of choices, and your `sides != range(3, 9)` expression was always true, meaning the `elif` test would be true any time `if slides == 8` was not true.

You can simplify your code by using a [*dictionary*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). It lets you associate a key with a value; make the numbers your keys, and you can simply test if `sides` is in the dictionary, or return a *default value* if it is not:

```
shape_msg = "Your shape is the "
result = {
    3: shape_msg + "triangle",
    4: shape_msg + "square",
    5: shape_msg + "pentagon",
    6: shape_msg + "hexagon",
    7: shape_msg + "heptagon",
    8: shape_msg + "octagon",
}

sides = int(input("How many sides on the shape are there? "))
result = results.get(sides, "You should enter a number between 3 and 8")
print(result)
```

Here, the [`dict.get()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) returns the value for the given key, or the default value if the key is not present.

If you need to continue the loop, test for the presence of the key and branch based on that:

```
while True:
    sides = int(input("How many sides on the shape are there? "))
    if sides in result:
        print(sides[result])
        break  # done, exit the loop
     print("You should enter a number between 3 and 8")
```

For further tips on how to ask a user for input and handle their wrong input, see [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response).

Comment: Thank you this worked for me.                                                                                 #Sides and shapes
result = {
    3: "Your shape is the triangle",
    4: "Your shape is the square",
    5: "Your shape is the pentagon",
    6: "Your shape is the hexagon",
    7: "Your shape is the heptagon",
    8: "Your shape is the octagon",
}

sides = int(input("How many sides on the shape are there? "))
result = result.get(sides, "You should enter a number between 3 and 8")
print(result)

Comment: 2nd assignment posted, problems.

Comment: Post a **new** question for a new problem please.

Comment: I have to wait 90 minutes :(

Comment: Yes, and those limits are there for a reason. We aim to be a collection of quality questions and even better answers with lasting value for future visitors, not a one-on-one mentoring facility. Try to work out your problem on your own in the meantime.

Comment: Worked on it and can get it out put late and never but with the on time its hard as it has a space and its two worded.

Answer (score 1):

Your `elif` is only "associated" with the previous `if`, so it will hit that `elif` for anything that is not an octagon, then as others have noticed your comparison is not testing if you're in the right range, you're comparing an int against a list.

Probably you really want all of your `if` statements except the first to be `elif` and the one you have as an `elif` to be the `else` clause for that whole block.

Better still, you could have a dictionary that maps the number of sides to the message, and if you don't have a key in the dictionary you can print the error message.

For the loop, if you put the whole thing in `while True` you could `break` after each success and not after the invalid number of sides, which would cause it to repeat the loop until they finally enter a valid number.

Answer (score 0):

`range(x, y)` outputs a range of numbers between `x` and `y`. You're then comparing an integer (which is the value of sides) to a list. Obviously it isn't equal to the list, because it is an integer!

Answer (score 0):

Look at last `if` `6!= [3,4,5,6,7,8]` , so your code will enter `elif` statement and `print ("You should enter a number between 3 and 8")` will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You've already covered all the legal answers with your `if` and `elif` statements, so there's no need to do any specific checking of other values.

Just change the last statement into an `else`:

```
else:
    print ("You should enter a number between 3 and 8")
```

Comment: They need to alter almost every other `if` statement too. *Just* changing that one `elif` to `else` is *not enough*.

Comment: Oops, I thought all the `if`s after the first were `elif`s.  If they were, I think my answer would stand.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this (and it seems to work) :

```
invalidAnswer = True
while invalidAnswer :
    invalidAnswer = False
    sides = int(input("How many sides on the shape are there? "))
    if sides ==3:
        print ("Your shape is the triangle")
    elif sides ==4:
        print ("Your shape is the square")
    elif sides ==5:
        print ("Your shape is the pentagon")
    elif sides ==6:
        print ("Your shape is the hexagon")
    elif sides ==7:
        print ("Your shape is the heptagon")
    elif sides ==8:
        print ("Your shape is the octagon")
    else :
        print ("You should enter a number between 3 and 8")
        invalidAnswer = True
```